# CORS working well in IIS Express, but fails in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've been working on this issue for two days.  If I create a new project following the [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), and run it through IIS Express, it works fine.  As soon as I switch it to IIS, it fails.

So, when hosted in Express I send:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:63274/api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63274
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:4001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4001/admin/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcSGVicmFcTWluZGZsYXllclxNaW5kZmxheWVyXGFwaVx0ZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 15:45:48 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And after the preflight:

```
PUT http://localhost:63274/api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63274
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:4001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4001/admin/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 17
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcSGVicmFcTWluZGZsYXllclxNaW5kZmxheWVyXGFwaVx0ZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 15:45:48 GMT

PUT: Test message
```

And when hosted from IIS I send (an identical request of):

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:4013/api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4013
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:4001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4001/admin/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 15:50:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And after the preflight:

```
PUT http://localhost:4013/api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4013
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:4001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4001/admin/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: private
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Monsters/4.0
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 15:47:58 GMT
Content-Length: 5298

... standard iis 500 page content...
```

The OPTIONS request and response from both is practially identical; the only change is the host (port) and timestamps.  However, after the preflight, when hosted in IIS it responds with `405 Method Not Allowed` and a different header `Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE`.

Is there something I need to add to the web.config for IIS specifically?

1. I'm just using the Chrome devtools to create an XMLHttpRequest for testing.
2. I have already removed WebDav from IIS.
3. The web.config is setup exactly as it would be from the linked tutorial.
4. I am running Windows 10 and IIS 10.
5. The only module I have installed is [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), but no rules are enabled (and it is not configured in the web.config).

Thanks in advance for any hints as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled WebDav then rebooted.

It's working.

...

Kill me.